# AWS Lambda - processing some data sequentially and some in parallel

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to process users requests, those requests are objects (JSON) with some parts identifying the request and some parts are request data, something like this

```
{
  group: "ABCDEFG",
  payload: {
    whatever: "something",
    somethingElse: 5
  }
}
```

where `group` identifies the request and `payload` is request data

and I need:

1. requests with the same group must be processed sequentially exactly in order they arrived (I'm aware that would mean it's blocking, subsequent requests must wait for previous to finish, that is ok)
2. requests with different groups can be processed in parallel (and is preferred to be processed in parallel)
3. I need response from the processing (Lambda) to return to user (that means SQS message group id is not the answer, SQS would make the processing asynchronous, thus losing the Lambda response)
4. the content of group is unknown and the number of groups is unknown (I cannot have specific number of identical lambdas and route particular groups to them)

Is this solvable using some native/direct AWS approach? I know some "hacky" ways to do it, but is there "a way to do it correctly"?

Comment: You are correct that this matches an Amazon SQS FIFO queue quite nicely, except for the need to return a response to the user. How would these requests come from users -- are they HTTP requests? -- and how would requests 'wait' if there are others with the same `group` being processed? Please tell us more about how the Input and Output would work in your design?

Comment: Hi, yes, regular HTTP requests (so asynchronous response using websockets is out of question, this must be request/response)

How would they wait? Not sure, how to answer... normally? Any request to API Gateway or AppSync waits until there is a response... but somewhere on the way, request with already existing group must wait until previous is finished. Fairly normal behavior as if you have more requests that you have e.g. Apache threads/processes.... some wait until previous are processed (socket still open, just waiting for delayed response)...

Comment: There is no 'communication' between AWS Lambda functions. Therefore, one function would not 'know' that another Lambda function is processing a particular request unless the information is shared via a database or caching layer. Can you tell us more about your actual application? That is, can you tell us what you are actually doing -- it might lead to some ideas for alternative implementations. Also, how long does a request take to process? You would need to avoid timeouts if other requests are causing it to block and the requests are queueing.

Comment: Is AWS Lambda an absolute requirement? I don't think this is going to work at all with Lambda.

Comment: It's a billing module, and you cannot perform multiple billing operations on one account at the same time... Operations themselves could be quite fast (under 50ms).


Lambda is not requirement, if I were to write dedicated server (from binding TCP socket on some address and listening to HTTP requests), I could write it, it's not that hard, if I had full control of requests distribution, but I do not want server running all the time on EC2 unless absolutely necessary...

Comment: to answer the question directly, whatever native AWS functionality can do this, I'm fine with it